# Adding AsParallel() call cause my code to break on writing a file

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I'm building a console application that have to process a bunch of document.

To stay simple, the process is :

1. for each year between X and Y, query the DB to get a list of document reference to process
2. for each of this reference, process a local file

The process method is, I think, independent and should be parallelized as soon as input args are different :

```
private static bool ProcessDocument(
        DocumentsDataset.DocumentsRow d,
        string langCode
)
{         
        try
        {                           
            var htmFileName = d.UniqueDocRef.Trim() + langCode + ".htm";
            var htmFullPath = Path.Combine("x:\path", htmFileName;

            missingHtmlFile = !File.Exists(htmFullPath);

            if (!missingHtmlFile)
            {
                var html = File.ReadAllText(htmFullPath);

                // ProcessHtml is quite long : it use a regex search for a list of reference
                // which are other documents, then sends the result to a custom WS

                ProcessHtml(ref html);

                File.WriteAllText(htmFullPath, html);

            }

            return true;             
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("{0,8}Fail processing {1} : {2}","[FATAL]", d.UniqueDocRef, exc.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In order to enumerate my document, I have this method :

```
    private static IEnumerable<DocumentsDataset.DocumentsRow> EnumerateDocuments()
    {           
        return Enumerable.Range(1990, 2020 - 1990).AsParallel().SelectMany(year => {
            return Document.FindAll((short)year).Documents;
        });
    }
```

`Document` is a business class that wrap the retrieval of documents. The output of this method is a typed dataset (I'm returning the Documents table). The method is waiting for a year and I'm sure a document can't be returned by more than one year (year is part of the key actually).

Note the use of `AsParallel()` here, but I never got issue with this one.

Now, my main method is :

```
        var documents = EnumerateDocuments();

        var result = documents.Select(d => {
            bool success = true;
            foreach (var langCode in new string[] { "-e","-f" })
            {
                success &= ProcessDocument(d, langCode);
            }
            return new { 
                d.UniqueDocRef,
                success
            };
        });
        using (var sw = File.CreateText("summary.csv"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Level;UniqueDocRef");
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                string level;
                if (!item.success) level = "[ERROR]";
                else level = "[OK]";

                sw.WriteLine(
                    "{0};{1}",
                    level,
                    item.UniqueDocRef
                    );
                //sw.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
```

This method works as expected under this form. However, if I replace

```
        var documents = EnumerateDocuments();
```

by

```
        var documents = EnumerateDocuments().AsParrallel();
```

It stops to work, and I don't understand why.

The error appears exactly here (in my process method):

```
File.WriteAllText(htmFullPath, html);
```

It tells me that the file is already opened by another program.

I don't understand what can cause my program not to works as expected. As my `documents` variable is an `IEnumerable` returning unique values, why my process method is breaking ?

thx for advises

**[Edit]** Code for retrieving document :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all documents in data store
    /// </summary>
    public static DocumentsDS FindAll(short? year)
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(connStringName); // MS Entlib

        DbCommand cm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Document_Select");
        if (year.HasValue) db.AddInParameter(cm, "Year", DbType.Int16, year.Value);

        string[] tableNames = { "Documents", "Years" };
        DocumentsDS ds = new DocumentsDS();
        db.LoadDataSet(cm, ds, tableNames);

        return ds;
    }
```

**[Edit2]** Possible source of my issue, thanks to mquander. If I wrote :

```
        var test = EnumerateDocuments().AsParallel().Select(d => d.UniqueDocRef);

        var testGr = test.GroupBy(d => d).Select(d => new { d.Key, Count = d.Count() }).Where(c=>c.Count>1);

        var testLst = testGr.ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(testLst.Where(x => x.Count == 1).Count());
        Console.WriteLine(testLst.Where(x => x.Count > 1).Count());
```

I get this result :

```
0
1758
```

Removing the AsParallel returns the same output.

Conclusion : my EnumerateDocuments have something wrong and returns twice each documents.

Have to dive here I think

This is probably my source enumeration in cause

Comment: parallel won't help much because oft the I/O.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: it's possible. I have to benchmark it. Before that, I'd like to solve my concurrency issue for my own sanity and knowledge.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: after having solved my issue, I measure my program. Using a single thread to process 5000 documents, it tooks 35 seconds. Adding AsParallel() method reduces the process to 8 seconds. Which is near a division per 4 (I'm on a quad thread processor... logic). What I didn't mention, is the kind of job in the process document. It parse the content of the file, perform a reg search for a list of reference, replace by something, and send the result to a WS to store externally the transformation. So I have a bit heavy string job + latency for constructing and sending soap message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Document.FindAll((short)year).Documents` threadsafe?  Because the difference between the first and the second version is that in the second (broken) version, this call is running multiple times concurrently.  That could plausibly be the cause of the issue.

Comment: I suppose. it's a simple sproc call (I added the body of the method in my question)

Comment: Can you verify that it's coming back with a collection of totally distinct years and not giving you the same year twice?  Because given your code, it's easy to imagine that something like `GetStoredProcCommand` and `AddInParameter` could be mixing up the parameters from concurrent calls (if it wasn't designed to be threadsafe.)

Comment: take a look at my edit. There is probably something wrong in my EnumerateDocuments methods.... just have to find what ;)

Comment: You put me on the right track. My Enumerate documents was returning differents records, but some with the same key because of a DB join. that was the root of my problems.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to have each task put the file data into a global queue and have a parallel thread take writing requests from the queue and do the actual writing.

Anyway, the performance of writing in parallel on a single disk is much worse than writing sequentially, because the disk needs to spin to seek the next writing location, so you are just bouncing the disk around between seeks. It's better to do the writes sequentially.

Comment: +1 -- this producer/consumer strategy is probably the best overall approach.

Comment: @mquander: Ironically this suggestion is nearly identical to mine from an abstract sense yet a lot more complicated for someone who didn't understand write locks on files. I still agree that this design is better than mine so +1 from me

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're trying to write to the same file. Only one thread/program can write to a file at a given time, so you can't use Parallel.

If you're reading from the same file, then you need to open the file with only read permissions as not to put a write lock on it.

The simplest way to fix the issue is to place a lock around your File.WriteAllText, assuming the writing is fast and it's worth parallelizing the rest of the code.

Comment: This...doesn't really answer his question of what's going wrong, and putting a lock around the file I/O both defeats the entire purpose of the parallelization and hides the problem.

Comment: His question is "why it's not working". I stated why and how to *easily* fix the issue and I also stated the downfall of my fix. He's trying to do something that can't be done, he needs to re-arch his design. While my answer isn't the best answer, it is a correct answer.

Comment: Well, I point out simply that if he had taken this suggestion, he would never have found the actual bug (as he has explained in his post), and he would still be writing every file twice; aside from doing twice as much work, there might be something else broken as a result.  This kind of "fix" is dangerous; fix the bug, don't work around it.